# Need loop to terminate after there's no input left to process

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int size = 81;
    char letters[size];


    cout << "Enter the string to be converted." << endl;

    cin.getline(letters, size);
    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        if ((letters[count] >= 97) && (letters[count] <= 122))
        {
            letters[count] -= 32;
            cout << letters[count];
        }
        else
        {
            cout << letters[count];
        }
    }

    cout << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, it works fine except it adds a bunch of ╠ at the end until it reaches 80 characters.  I just need it to terminate the loop as soon as it converts all the letters that were inputted to uppercase.  I thought that the two arguments for cin.getline would define the elements in the array and how many elements there are.  Not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: Loop until `letters[count] == '\0'`. Strings are null terminated.

Comment: if (letters[count] == '\0')
      {
       break;
      }?

Comment: Use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and iterators or [ranged for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)?

Comment: `>= 97`, `<= 122`, and `-= 32` are quite obscure. Your aim should be for the code to be immediately obvious. `islower` and `toupper` do just that. Once you have those there, you might realize that you can replace the whole thing with a simple `toupper` and get rid of the `if` entirely.

Comment: By the way, Microsoft's compiler generally fills uninitialized values with 0xCC bytes. ╠ is the CP-437 (think MS-DOS) character with the value 0xCC (204), just like how 'a' is 97 in almost every encoding. If you use the debugger that's just a click away in Visual Studio, I believe it shows characters with both the glyph and the numerical value.

Comment: A better approach would be to use `std::string letters;` instead of a char array, and then you can loop based on the string size.  The existing code will cause a buffer overflow if too much input is entered.

Comment: @M.M, There's at least a size argument to `cin.getline` to prevent that, but it's certainly not ideal. `std::string` is definitely preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

> for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)

into this:

```
for (int count = 0; Letters[Count] != '\0'; count++)
```